# Adding Wiki Type Content to Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

Has there every been any consideration given to adding the ability to create "wiki" type content on Stack Overflow?

I'm sure there are pros and cons and it's possible that it just straight up doesn't fit into the mission of SO. I feel like sometimes I hunt around for an answer to a question though, and sometimes it may take multiple different Stack Overflow questions to arrive at it, but I eventually do, and it would be nice if there was a convenient way to synthesize that information into a succinct blog type article such that the next person doesn't need to do the same work of digesting all the various questions in order to arrive at their answer.

Obviously there are a lot of other venues to do something like this so maybe the answer is just "write a blog elsewhere" ... was just curious if this has ever come up before.

Comment: There is [meta-tag:community-wiki], [meta-tag:self-answer], and there was [meta-tag:documentation].

Comment: @Xufox self-answer seems like a really good fit for what I am talking about actually, I had never seen that tag before. Thanks!

Comment: Tag wikis. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/be-proud-of-tag-wikis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Has there every been any consideration given to adding the ability to create "wiki" type content on Stack Overflow?

Yes and it exists. See [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

> if there was a convenient way to synthesize that information into a succinct blog type article such that the next person doesn't need to do the same work of digesting all the various questions in order to arrive at their answer.

The "blog" suggestion would go completely against SO's principle of being a Q&A site, as for collating the content to make it easier to find answers, we have the duplicate system which does this rather well.

If you wish to make an answer *more* open to community changes, you can make it a *community wiki* answer.

It is also possible to answer your own questions *and* it is also advocated<sup>1</sup> to make canonical questions when appropriate.

---

<sup>1</sup> with the caveat that the question is formed correctly and is actually on-topic